# rolling user defined functions on entire dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas has a `df.rolling(N).apply(f)` functionality that applies `f` to each column of `df` using a rolling window of size `N`. However, how can I apply a rolling function on the entire dataframe? That is, rather than `f` receiving each column of `df` one at a time, I would like all the columns to be passed to `f` like the way `df.apply(f)` would do.

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate of the linked question. It is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55990574/2954547 instead.