# Pandas rolling apply function to entire window dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply, rolling-computation

I want to apply a function to a rolling window. All the answers I saw here are focused on applying to a single row / column, but I would like to apply my function to the entire window. Here is a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [ [1,2], [3,4], [3,4], [6,6], [9,1], [11,2] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AB'), data=data)
```

This is `df`:

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   3   4
3   6   6
4   9   1
5   11  2
```

Take some function to apply to the *entire* window:

```
df.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.shape)
```

In this example, I would like to get something like:

```
    some_name   
0   NA  
1   NA  
2   (3,2)   
3   (3,2)   
4   (3,2)   
5   (3,2)
```

Of course, the shape is used as an example showing `f` treats the entire window as the object of calculation, not just a row / column. I tried playing with the `axis` keyword for `rolling`, as well as with the `raw` keyword for `apply` but with no success. Other methods (`agg, transform`) do not seem to deliver either.

Sure, I can do this with a list comprehension. Just thought there is an easier / cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Maybe something like this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180324/bin-pandas-dataframe-by-every-x-rows

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question?  With pandas I don't think there's a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not with `pd.DataFrame.rolling` .... that function is applied iteratively to the columns, taking in a series of floats/NaN, and returning a series of floats/NaN, one-by-one.  I think you'll have better luck with your intuition....

```
def rolling_pipe(dataframe, window, fctn):
    return pd.Series([dataframe.iloc[i-window: i].pipe(fctn) 
                      if i >= window else None 
                      for i in range(1, len(dataframe)+1)],
                     index = dataframe.index) 

df.pipe(rolling_pipe, 3, lambda x: x.shape)
```

Comment: could you maybe briefly explain what this is doing? Thanks!

Comment: Sure-- `pd.DataFrame.pipe` is an incredibly useful method.  It takes a function as its argument.  The function's first input is a pd.DataFrame.  To get the most power from `pipe`, you usually want it returning a `Series` or `DataFrame` object so that you can chain these pipes together... but that's a separate topic.

Comment: In this case, we know that we want to "rolling apply" a function to subsets of the dataframe, starting with a first "cut" of the dataframe which we'll define using the `window` param, get a value returned from `fctn` on that cut of the dataframe (with `.iloc[..].pipe(fctn)`, and then keep rolling down the dataframe this way (with the list comprehension).  In this case, the obvious object we want to return is a pd.Series object with the same index (`index=dataframe.index`) as the input dataframe.

Comment: also two notes: 1, `fctn` here is a function that expects a `pd.DataFrame` as input, and then assumes a non-iterable output like a number or string.  There is a version of this function that could return dataframes instead of series, just not as its written above.  2, since this post I've come across a similar looking function called `pd.rolling_apply`, but the documentation for it is lacking, so you'd have to test it yourself to see if it's doing the same thing as `rolling_pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

The argument supplied to your apply function is a Series with an index property containing start, stop and step properties.

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

You can use this to query your data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Sean', i) for i in range(1,11)], columns=['name', 'value'])

def func(series):
    view = df.iloc[series.index]
    # use view to do something...
    count = len(view[view.value.isin([1,2,8])])
    return count

df['count'] = df.value.rolling(2).apply(func)
```

There may be a more efficient way to do this but I'm not sure how.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need rolling application over a datetime-like index, the other answers are not sufficient.

You have to resort to manually iterating over the `Rolling` object, and reconstructing the result into a `Series` or `DataFrame` as needed:

```py
from datetime import (
    datetime as DateTime,
    timedelta as TimeDelta,
)
import pandas as pd

now = DateTime.now(tz=TimeZone.utc)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'t': now + TimeDelta(days=1), 'x': 11, 'y': 21},
    {'t': now + TimeDelta(days=2), 'x': 12, 'y': 22},
    {'t': now + TimeDelta(days=3), 'x': 13, 'y': 23},
    {'t': now + TimeDelta(days=4), 'x': 14, 'y': 24},
]).set_index('t')

results = {}
for group in df.rolling('2D'):
    # Perform a silly calculation, in this case an aggregation
    result = group['y'].min() * group['x'].max()
    # Choose a value to use as the resulting index
    index = group.index.min()
    results[index] = result
results = pd.Series(results)
print(results)
```

```
2022-07-15 01:41:05.121823+00:00    252
2022-07-16 01:41:05.121823+00:00    286
2022-07-17 01:41:05.121823+00:00    322
dtype: int64
```

This works analogously to iterating over a `GroupBy` object. Unfortunately however, and unlike with `GroupBy`, iterating does *not* yield the actual bounds that are used for the rolling window. I am not aware of a way to manually obtain these.

I expected that this should also be possible with the new `method=` kwarg in `DataFrame.rolling`, but I wasn't able to get it to work properly. I will post a separate answer if I figure it out!