# Obtaining minimal index with .rolling

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider pandas frames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2])
df_top = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
label_frame = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I want to do the following thing:

If any of numbers `df.iloc[0:3]` is greater than `df_top.iloc[0]`, then we assign to first element of `label_frame` minimal index for which this is satisfied.

For the first iteration it should look like this:

My program checks: `df.iloc[0] > df_top.iloc[0] False`, `df.iloc[1] > df_top.iloc[0] True` `df.iloc[2] > df_top.iloc[0] True`, so it should replace first element of `label_frame` with 1 since its the minimal index for which this inequality is satisfied.

I want to iterate this programme for whole data frame `df` using `.rolling` function combined with `.apply`. (so the second example should be `df[1:4] > df_top[1]`, and we replace second element of label_frame).

Do you know how it can be done? I tried to play with a custom function, with `lambda`, but I have no idea how can I have rolling window of `df` and return minimal value of index for which the inequality is satisfied.

```
for i in range(len(label_frame) - 3):
    if (df.iloc[i:i+3] > df_top.iloc[i]).any()[0]:
        label_frame.iloc[i] = np.where(df.iloc[i:i+3] > df_top.iloc[i])[0].min()
label_frame.iloc[-2:, 0] = np.nan
label_frame

    0
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   0.0
4   0.0
5   0.0
6   0.0
7   NaN
8   NaN
```

Comment: Do you always want to do this with 3 elements, or many more?

Comment: I would always want to go three i.e. `df[0:3] > df_top[0]` then `df[1:4] > df_top[1]`, `df[2:5] > df_top[2]` and so on...

Comment: What happens for df[7:?] should it take two values only?

Comment: It can be filled with NaN's

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output?

Comment: Sure! I updated my question with the very primitive code written in an inefficient loop ;))

Comment: probably the answer you're looking for can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990574) i made a while back...

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, and if you only want to test 3 values, the easiest might be to use a 2D comparison:

```
a = df.assign(**{'1': df[0].shift(-1), '2': df[0].shift(-2)}).eq(df_top).to_numpy()
m = a.any(1)
label_frame[0] = df.index + np.where(m, a.argmax(1), np.nan)
```

output:

```
     0
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  NaN
6  NaN
7  NaN
8  NaN
```

Comment: I updated my question by adding an exemplary desired output. Could you please chceck it if we are on the same page?